# How to test a return value of a mock function in jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I want to test the return value of a mock function in jest.

In following code i want to mock fs module's mkdirSync function

```
const fs = require("fs");


describe("Testing mock fs.mkdirSync", () => {
    fs.mkdirSync = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(5);
    fs.mkdirSync("./apple");

    it("fs.mkdirSync must have been called", () => {
        expect(fs.mkdirSync).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    //This test fails with TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

    it("fs.mkdirSync last return value must be 5", () => {
        expect(fs.mkdirSync.mock.results[0].value).toBe(5);
    });



});
```

Second test fails with TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: In your example, you're doing exactly as the documentation for jest suggest. I copy-pasted your code and both tests passed in jest. There's something you've omitted that's making the test fail, because your code is fine.

Comment: i have installed jest globally, and my jest version is v20.04 and i am running the test with jest --watch

Comment: may i know which version jest you are using and how are you running the test

Comment: I've jest version 23.4.0. I'm running an npm script `"scripts": { ... "test": "jest" }`. The code is in a .test.js file. all in a project created with create-react-app.

Comment: but my create-react-app installs the jest version 20.0.4 how did you get the latest version of jest in create-react-app without ejecting it ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code is correct**, but your jest installation is an outdated version.

Copy-pasting your tests into a fresh create-react-app boilerplate and running jest will result in the behaviour described in the question.

run `npm install jest --save-dev` to install the latest version of jest.

Running jest now should result in both tests passing.

Comment: Thanks for answering , but i wonder jest by-default get installed with create-react-app via react scripts but why  does not it  install the latest version of jest.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you want to test the return value of a jest mocked function? At this point you are testing `jest`.

You could assign `fs.mkdirSync` to a variable and test that value since that is the returned value:

```
const result = fs.mkdirSync("./apple");
it("fs.mkdirSync last return value must be 5", () => {
    expect(result).toBe(5);
});
```

Comment: I have over simplified this example suppose my mock function could have been called inside another function and return value of that function depends on the arguments passed to the mock function. In such situation how to test the mock function